# What does "to resolve on making an early start" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/resolve_1):
**(1)** *We had resolved on making an early start*.

What does (1) mean?

Does (1) mean (2) or (3)?:
**(2)** *We had made a decision about whether to make an early start or not*.
**(3)** *We had made a decision. Our decision was to make an early start*.

Answer (score 2):

It means 3.

This use of *resolve* is rather old-fashioned - you'd be more likely to find *resolved to ...* rather than *resolved on ...-ing* now - but implies not just that they'd made a decision, but that they had decided to do whatever it was.

Comment: My apologies, @Loviii: I meant "3" when I wrote "2". Now corrected.

Comment: Colin - joy shall be in heaven over one sinner that repenteth...